# How to change the plot position in R markdown for a little bit

Tags: r, r-markdown

I know with

```
{r fig.align="center"}
```

I can put it center.
But how can I move my plot a little bit right, like to set the position using a numeric: `y=0.4`
I am generating the HTML.
I check the all fig.xxx but can not find a solution.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What output format are you using, e.g. HTML, PDF? Some solutions to this might be format-specific.

Comment: @Marius Thank you for the comment.  I am using HTML.

Comment: You could try `out.extra='style="margin-left: 150px;"'`and use the value or any other CSS properties you like.